# What is the logic behind Question 43?

Tags: the-impossible-quiz

**So, Question 43 of The Impossible Quiz is this:**

[image: The Impossible Quiz Question 43 (Bridget makes everyone...)]

The answer to this question, oddly enough, is Tom Cruise.

**But... why? I'm aware that it's supposed to be some sort of reference to Jerry Maguire, but I have no idea what it's supposed to mean.**

Comment: There's logic behind the questions in The Impossible Quiz?

Comment: Google came up with this, but frankly I still don't really understand the reference: http://impossible-quiz.wikia.com/wiki/Question_43_%28The_Impossible_Quiz%29

Comment: Hm, yeah, I remember seeing that. I can't get my head around that, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think answering this might require a little bit of speculation.. that said, there are two reasons I would have personally picked "Tom Cruise"

1. ***"The odd one out"*** is a general strategy I have found to work a lot in The Impossible Quiz. *Straight*, *Gay*, and *Bi* are sexual orientations. Tom Cruise is an actor. The odd one out wins.
2. ***Movie Referencing*** plays in a little bit. While people have said that [Bridget is a reference to Guilty Gears](http://guilty-gear.wikia.com/wiki/Bridget), I am not very familiar with this series. When I read the question, I immediately think of [Bridget Jones Diary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridget_Jones%27s_Diary). In the [film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridget_Jones%27s_Diary_%28film%29), the main character is played by [Renée Zellweger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9e_Zellweger), who's first major role was playing a character in the movie [Jerry Maguire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Maguire). Tom Cruise plays the role of Jerry.